# How are variables stacked into the stack in C?

Tags: c

> For parts a) and b) refer to the following code:
>
> ```
> void foo(int* p, int * q) { 
>     p = q; 
>     char* c = (char *) (p + 2); 
>     *c = 'x'; 
> } 
>
> int main() { 
>     char c[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
>     int i = 0; 
>     int j = 0; 
>     foo(&i, &j); 
>     printf("%s", c);
> }
> ```
>
> a) What does the main function print? ____________________________
>
> b) If we change the declaration and initialization of c in the second
> line of foo function to:
>
> ```
> int* c = p + 2;
> ```
>
> and the rest of the code remains the same, what does the main function
> print now?

The code is written in C and the answer to a is xello and answer to b is x. I'd like to know how such output came out and what had happened in the stack memory

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack usage is not defined by the standard. The compiler may do whatever it likes. Look at the assembler output to see what was created by that specific compiler on that specific hardware.

Comment: Pointer arithmetics beyond the limits of the addresses memory object is not allowed and causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: With the changes for b) the result dependens on endianess also.

Comment: I don't see how foo is doing anything useful. You are sending the addresses of `i` and `j` and doing what?

Comment: Where did you get this example from? Burn those materials!

Answer (score 4):

This code is just buggy - it has no deterministic output. Did you try to run it yourself? If you got this assignment in school, then it's a horrible assignment and whoever gave it should not be teaching C.

- `p = q;` here `p` points to the memory location of `int j`.
- `p + 2` here it performs pointer arithmetic on `int` type, stepping `2*sizeof(int)` bytes away, ending up out of bounds. This is undefined behavior ([see this](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277215)) and here anything can happen, including a program crash or instruction trap.
- The program is already potentially toast, but for the sake of completeness lets look at the rest. `(char *) (p + 2);`  means that this unknown address is cast to a character pointer.
- `*c = 'x';` This de-references a byte in the invalid, supposed `int` location. Which byte it gets would possibly depend on CPU endianess, particularly in case b).

Ignoring the undefined behavior bugs, you need to know the specific ABI, compiler and system in order to even attempt to speculate about the result. On the three mainstream x86 compilers gcc, clang and icc running on Linux, the output happened to be `hello`.